# Includ OptionSetValue in QueryExpression

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I need to query an `OptionSetValue` field to find active records according to a query done based on a specific Id. However, each time the query below executes I get the following error:

> the type with data contract name optionsetvalue is not expected

How do I include an `OptionSetValue` in the `Values` attribute of a `QueryExpression` `Condition`?

```
queryEx = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "account",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
    Criteria =
    {
        FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
        Conditions =
        {
            new ConditionExpression
            {
                AttributeName = "neu_id",
                Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                Values = {agency.ReferenceNumber}
            },
            new ConditionExpression
            {
                AttributeName = "neu_appointmentstatus",
                Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                Values = {new OptionSetValue(279660000)}
            }
        }
    }
};

EntityCollection collection = _client.RetrieveMultiple(queryEx);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your condition you need to set the integer value of the optionset.
So the code will be:

```
new ConditionExpression
    {
        AttributeName = "neu_appointmentstatus",
        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
        Values = 279660000
    }
```